# Alfresco pickerchildren.get.js is missing in codes

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm having a problem in locating webscript in Alfresco 4.2c. I need to extend its functionality. I found and edited pickerresults.ftl but to see the changes I need to locate it in src files in the repository. I found it extracted in tomcat directory but I cannot locate where it came from.

I found out that in community edition it should be in the alfresco remote api but cannot see it there.

Comment: Have you looked into JAR files as well? Note, the controler might be written in JS or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older version's src code was maintained in SVN. use share extensions to override the script. below link gives the src location:

https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/